# Php script not showing errors but only redirects to homepage

Tags: mysql, php, web-development

I am making e-commerce site and add to basket script not doing anything I expect it to insert data into shopping basket from products page that is working perfectly fine. Please have a look and help me figure it out.. it is not giving any syntax error or parse error it just dont do anything and when I click buy it just redirect me to homepage

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();
require("db.php");
require("functions.php");
$validid = pf_validate_number($_GET['id'], "redirect", $config_basedir);
$prodsql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = " . $_GET['id'] . ";";
$prodres = mysqli_query($prodsql);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($prodres);
$prodrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($prodres);
if($numrows == 0)
{     
  header("Location: " . $config_basedir);
} else {
  if($_POST['submit'])
  {
    if($_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM'])
    {
      $itemsql = "INSERT INTO orderitems(order_id, product_id, quantity) VALUES("
                 . $_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM'] . ", "
                 . $_GET['id'] . ", "
                 . $_POST['amountBox'] . ")";
      mysqli_query($itemsql);
    } else {
      if($_SESSION['SESS_LOGGEDIN'])
      {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO orders(customer_id, registered, date) VALUES("
               . $_SESSION['SESS_USERID'] . ", 1, NOW())";
        mysqli_query($sql);
        session_register("SESS_ORDERNUM");
        $_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM'] = mysqli_insert_id();
        $itemsql = "INSERT INTO orderitems(order_id, product_id, quantity) VALUES("
                   . $_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM']
                   . ", " . $_GET['id'] . ", "
                   . $_POST['amountBox'] . ")";
        mysqli_query($itemsql);
      } else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO orders(registered, date, session) VALUES("
               . "0, NOW(), '" . session_id() . "')";
        mysqli_query($sql);
        session_register("SESS_ORDERNUM");
        $_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM'] = mysqli_insert_id();
        $itemsql = "INSERT INTO orderitems(order_id, product_id, quantity) VALUES("
                   . $_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM'] . ", " . $_GET['id'] . ", " 
                   . $_POST['amountBox'] . ")";
        mysqli_query($itemsql);
      }
    }
    $totalprice = $prodrow['price'] * $_POST['amountBox'] ;
    $updsql = "UPDATE orders SET total = total + "
              . $totalprice . " WHERE id = "
              . $_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM'] . ";";
    mysqli_query($updres);
    header("Location: " . $config_basedir . "showcart.php");
  } else {
    require("header.php");
    echo "<form action='addtobasket.php?id="
         . $_GET['id'] . "' method='POST'>";
    echo "<table cellpadding='10'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    if(empty($prodrow['image'])) 
    {
      echo "<td><img src='./productimages/dummy.jpg' width='50' alt='"
           . $prodrow['name'] . "'></td>";
    } else {
      echo "<td><img src='./productimages/" . $prodrow['image']
           . "' width='50' alt='" . $prodrow['name']
           . "'></td>";
    }
      echo "<td>" . $prodrow['name'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>Select Quantity <select name='amountBox'>";
      for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++)
      {
        echo "<option>" . $i . "</option>";
      }
      echo "</select></td>";
      echo "<td><strong>&pound;"
           . sprintf('%.2f', $prodrow['price'])
           . "</strong></td>";
      echo "<td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add to basket'></td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      echo "</table>";
      echo "</form>";
   }
}
require("footer.php");

?>
```

Comment: You might want to narrow down a bit more - that's quite a lot of code you are asking to review. Have you tried simplyfiying the sciprt to a bare minimum (for the sake of troubleshooting?). For example, try writing a scirpt that submits to the same place, with hard-coded data (no form complexity) and check behaviour in that case. Also, do your Apache logs indicate anything happening? Adding logging lines might help trace the logic too.

Comment: Nice idea @taifwa on the logs. Ashking, open up a terminal and run `tail -f /var/log/apache2/*.log` then refresh the page and check if any errors get printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this section

```
$updsql = "UPDATE orders SET total = total + "
          . $totalprice . " WHERE id = "
          . $_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM'] . ";";
mysqli_query($updres);
```

You have a variable named `$updsql` but on the query, it is named `$updres`.

Comment: help me with this please 
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sae/worldz/addtobasket.php on line 12

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sae/worldz/addtobasket.php on line 13

Comment: Check your mysqli query and the result it returns. You can use `var_dump($result)`

Comment: i dont know how it works

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php or https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php for how these functions work.